# Метод save() не принимает ArraysList элементов?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Используя одну из старых версий spring-data-jpa 1.11.9.RELEASE столкнулся с непонятным моментом с Generics

у меня есть spring repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRecord, String> {}
```

Записываю так и все работает:

```
UserRecord user = new UserRecord ();
userRepository.save(user);
```

Но вижу, что помимо одиночной сущности, Репозиторий содержит так же метод с такой сигнатурой

```
<S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);
```

Поэтому я решил записывать сразу всю коллекцию своих элементов вместо записи по очереди

```
        Iterable<UserRecord> list = new ArrayList<>();
        userRepository.save(list);
```

Но, идея мне подчеркивает такое использование красным как неправильное со словами

> Incompatible types. Required UserRecord but 'save' was inferred to
>   Iterable: no instance(s) of type variable(s) S exist so that
>   Iterable conforms to UserRecord

Как записать коллекцию элементов разом?

Comment: Если в этой версии spring-data-jpa есть метод saveAll, то используйте его.

Comment: @Tema_Bel как раз в этом дело да, что его в этой версии нет, но просто save судя по сигнатуре метода должен уметь принимать интерфейс Iterable. А ArrayList - реализует этот интерфейс.

Answer (score 0):

У меня все скомпилировалось. Сравните с вашей реализацией.

UserRepository:

```
package ru.abelash.stackoverflow;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRecord, String> {}
```

UserRecord:

```
package ru.abelash.stackoverflow;

public class UserRecord {}
```

Test:

```
package ru.abelash.stackoverflow;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        UserRepository userRepository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);

        UserRecord user = new UserRecord();
        userRepository.save(user);

        Iterable<UserRecord> list = new ArrayList<>();
        userRepository.save(list);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.abelash</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта]